# C++: Declaration of "extern reference"

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, extern

I want to declare a variable as `extern double&` and use it's pointer in a `static const struct`. Somewhere else I want to define the variable to be actually a member of another struct. The code attached works on `x86` as I expect.

Problem is that it does not work in an embedded `ARM` context: The `void* void_pointer` inside the initialized `static const struct` there is just `NULL`, while everything else looks valid.

Is the syntax I try here possible and defined in the Standard, or some detail implementation defined? How would I debug this? What can go wrong? What is actually happending here?

```
#include <iostream>

// declare and define place where the actual content is stored
struct storage_struct { double double_array[2]; double double_variable; };
struct storage_struct db = {{3.0,4.0},1.0};

// declare "double_reference" as extern
extern double &double_reference;

// declare and defince a struct to hold the pointer to the extern reference:
struct target_struct { void *void_pointer; };
static const struct target_struct dut { &double_reference };

// and now connect the "extern refernce" to an actual value from the database-struct
double &double_reference = db.double_variable;

int main() {

    std::cout << "testPrint with initial values:\n";
    std::cout << "void pointer: '" << dut.void_pointer << "', value: '"
              << *(double *)dut.void_pointer << "'\n";
    std::cout << "\n";

    // change content in the database
    db.double_variable = 11.0;
    db.double_array[0] = 1444.0;
    db.double_array[1] = 238947.0;

    std::cout << "adress of storage_struct: " << &db << "\n";
    std::cout << "adress of double_variable: " << &db.double_variable << "\n";
    std::cout << "adress of double_reference: " << &double_reference << "\n";
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "testPrint with changed values:\n";
    std::cout << "void pointer: '" << dut.void_pointer << "', value: '"
              << *(double *)dut.void_pointer << "'\n";
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Compile and execute with: `g++ -std=c++11 -o test main.cpp && ./test` -- works like a charm. Flash this to an ARM **µC** -- `void_pointer` is 0x00... (Note that it also works on Debian `ARM`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's interesting that this works on x86; I wouldn't have expected it to. `dut.void_pointer` is initialised before `double_reference` because it is defined first in the code. The fix is to reverse the order of instantiation:

```
// first initialise the reference
double &double_reference = db.double_variable;

// then take the pointer, when it has a defined value.
static const struct target_struct dut { &double_reference };
```

Comment: Thats why the variable is first declared as `extern double&`. The linker will connect them. In another version of this test the different parts are spread over different compile-units -- thats works as well on x86

Comment: If the variables are spread over several translation units, you run headlong into the static initialisation order fiasco. The linker finds the reference, yes, but since the reference may not have been initialised when the pointer is initialised, the pointer's value is unspecified.

Comment: So moving the `static const struct dut` into some init-function solves the actual problem on the µC side **thanks!** But I'm not convinced that the *static initialization order fiasco* is my real problem. The code posted in my question is in _one_ TU and does not work on the µC... And there is no constructor called...?

Comment: The code posted in your question initialises the pointer before the reference, so the pointer has an unspecified value (and your program undefined behaviour).

Comment: Hm. And `-fsanitize=address` might detect this?

Comment: It's always worth a try, I suppose. I'd not expect it to find this, though, because it would be easier to catch the error at compile time. I'm a bit annoyed neither gcc nor clang warn here, to tell you the truth. I guess it's such a corner case that nobody thought of it.